# Given an index in a string of HTML, find the closest (parent) DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string, containing only the following HTML:

```
<p id="p1">Hello there</p>
<p id="p2">Hello there</p>
```

The "o" of the first "Hello" is at index 15 inside of the string.

Given an index `i`, such as `i = 15`, I want to find what HTML DOM the character at this index is in.

In my example it is in paragraph `id="p1"`.

How can I programmatically find out which parent DOM the character at index `i` is inside a string of markup?

---

The implementation is this: we have several changes to an article's HTML, with each diff denoted by a start index and an end index. How do we get the paragraph of the article that the change resides in?

At first I thought of using jQuery's :contains, where we can find the DOM of the change given that we know what it is. But if the change is a single space, the search will find multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new div element, from index 0 to 16. Find last div inside new created div element.

```js
var html = $("#content").html();
var index = 16;
var d = $("<div></div>");

d.html(html.substr(0, index));

var result = d.find("p").last();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p id="p1">Hello there</p>
  <p id="p2">Hello there</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that is clever.  I think OP was wanting the `id` of the element, but I still `+1`

Comment: Just add `.attr('id')` to the end.

Comment: This assumes that the index is always in the text of an element. If it's in the tag, you'll create invalid HTML when you do the `substr()`.